# Indicators library in svg, vml or canvas

Tags: graphics, svg, icons, html5-canvas, vml

I am working on an application where I need to display color coded indicators. The standard colors will be red/amber/green, but I need to be able to pick any color (e.g. by hex value). The colors are updated dynamically by a script, based on data (dashboard style).

Are there libraries that could help me? I am thinking in particular about using svg or canvas graphics that the script could modify.

Note: the question has been rephrased to better explain the context.

Comment: I'd be interested to know why there are 3 close requests on this question related to svg and canvas (and on which I received excellent answers btw).

Comment: @AndrewBarber maybe I should rephrase my question then? I explicitly asked about code (svg or canvas), and excluded image formats. As a side note, I really appreciate that you left a comment.

Comment: @AndrewBarber damn! It made sense to me, especially as raphael seems to be a good fit. Of course I am ready to reconsider my choice if I get more replies, especially now that I have made significant edits to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of links to start with:

- [nounproject](http://thenounproject.com/)
- [openiconlibrary](http://openiconlibrary.sourceforge.net/)
- [openclipart](http://openclipart.org)
- [small iconset](http://raphaeljs.com/icons/) for use with raphaël

Comment: Thanks! It seems that openiconlibrary and openclipart are png, right?

Comment: Well, they both have png files too, but a large portion the files are svg.

Answer (score 1):

I like this collection on WikiCommons. They are in SVG

http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Tango_icons

Comment: wow! Could you point me to the license terms, I couldn't find them in the page.

Comment: Good question.  If you follow the link off that page to here: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Desktop_icons_2.20 it says they are under GPL v2.  The ones I pointed you to appear to be a sub-set of the ones on that but it isn't clearly labelled.